# Re-Initiate flexslider to start animation from first child

Tags: jquery

I have 3 set of div's:

```
<div id="img_collections_g1" class="flexslider">
                               <ul class="slides productPic">
                                    <li>
                                    <img id="img_gam_1" src="resources/desktop/Comp-1.png"  />
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                    <img id="img_gam_2"  src="resources/desktop/_Layer-Comp-1-copy.png"   />
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                    <img id="img_gam_3"  src="resources/desktop/_Layer-Comp-2.png"   />
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

<div id="img_collections_ga2" class="flexslider">
                               <ul class="slides productPic">
                                    <li>
                                    <img id="img_gam2_1" src="resources/desktop/Comp-1.png"  />
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                    <img id="img_ga22"  src="resources/desktop/Comp-1-copy.png"   />
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                    <img id="img_ga2o_3"  src="resources/desktop/-Comp-2.png"   />
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

<div id="img_collections_g3" class="flexslider">
                               <ul class="slides productPic">
                                    <li>
                                    <img id="img_gam3o_1" src="resources/desktop/omp-1.png"  />
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                    <img id="img_gam3o_2"  src="resources/desktop/Comp-1-copy.png"   />
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                    <img id="img_gam3_3"  src="resources/desktop/Comp-2.png"   />
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
```

They are sliding right to left on click.

ALL 3 has flexslider plugin embedded in it.

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
easing: "swing",  
animation: "fade",
slideshowSpeed: 2000,
animationSpeed: 1,
touch: true,
controlsContainer: ".flex-container",
start: function(slider){
  funSETBottomSec();
},
after: function(slider){
    funSETBottomSec();
//$(".flex-control-nav li").removeClass("active");
    //$(".flex-active").parent().addClass("active");
}
});
```

i want , when i click "next" to slide to "next" div , i want to re-initiate flexslider and it should start from 1st "li" image,
currently it is starting from last div's position.

i am also calling this function on "next" click but didn't worked for me.

any solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). 
Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), or flag your question and ask a moderator to migrate it.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting the property:

```
 animationLoop: true
```